# Aframe component with dependencies on component with multiple true

Tags: aframe

I am writing a custom component that I would like to define other component dependencies.

The dependencies are different animations types.
Let's say they have the names "animation__x" and "animation__y"
x and y can be any name, so I am looking for something like animation__*
or /animation__\s*/

The only way I have made this work at the moment is either ensuring my component is placed after the animation components on the HTML or alternatively to force update components using this.el.updateComponents()

Neither of these solutions feels right to me.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cool-component', {
    dependencies: ['animation'],
    update: functions(data){
       //detect available animations and do some stuff with them
       let animations = Object.keys(components).filter((key) => {
           return /(^animation__\w*)/.test(key);
       });
       //animations results in an empty array
    }
});
```

html that is not working

```
<a-scene cool-component animation__x="" animation__y="" animation__z=""></a-scene>
```

html that is working (but its not good as I cant ensure my component is always last in the list

```
<a-scene animation__x="" animation__y="" animation__z="" cool-component></a-scene>
```

js that works, but doesnt feel write as I am using the entities internal functions

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cool-component', {
    dependencies: ['animation'],
    update: functions(data){
       this.el.updateComponents(); //<-- I DONT LIKE THIS BUT IT WORKS
       //detect available animations and do some stuff with them
       //now all animations are available as this.el.components
       let animations = Object.keys(components).filter((key) => {
           return /(^animation__\w*)/.test(key);
       });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options:

Depend on the specific component names: `dependencies: ['animation__xxx']`

Make `cool-component` set those animations:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('cool-component', {
    init: functions(data){
       this.el.setAttribute('animation__xxx', {...});
    }
});
```

You can also defer `cool-component` logic until the entity has loaded and all the components have initialized:

```
init: function () {
  this.el.addEvenListener(‘loaded’, this.doStuffAferComponentsLoad.bind(this));
}
```

More details in what `cool-component` is trying to accomplish will help to get a more precise answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could use animationcomplet events of animations like this which is really awesome. And I wish my qusetion as about that cause its an awesome answer.

I have updated my question to include use case details and code samples.

Comment: I need the animation names to be dynamic, so I ended up using the event listener "loaded" event.